# Property of ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:R→R′$ be a ring homomorphism with ker$f$ not equal to $R$. $R′$ is a integral domain with unity $1′$ and $R$ is a ring with unity $1$. Prove $f(1)=1′$.

Comment: $f(1^2) = f(1)^2$ so $f(1)=1$ or $f(1)=0$. Why the case $f(1)=0$ don't help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any $u\in R\setminus \mbox{Ker}f$ then $f(u) = f(1\cdot u ) = f(1) \cdot f(u) $ hence $$0=f(u)-f(1) \cdot f(u) = f(u) (1' -f(1))$$ and since $R'$ is integral domain and $f(u)\neq 0$ we obtain that $$1'-f(1) =0.$$

Comment: @SayantanKoley, if you are satisfied with this answer, you can click on the checkmark to accept it as an answer.